# Sql database to another pc-sql database

Tags: c#, sql

i'm using this code:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(" MERGE customermaster AS target USING Tamio.dbo.memberform AS source ON target.id = source.id WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET target.name = source.name WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT (id, name) VALUES (source.id, source.name);", con);
```

I want to choose from my local database.

I try this but it says incorrect syntax

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(" MERGE customermaster AS target USING [local]Tamio.dbo.memberform AS source ON target.id = source.id WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET target.name = source.name WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT (id, name) VALUES (source.id, source.name);", con);
```

Also this is my local connection

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(local);Initial Catalog=Tamio;Integrated Security=True");
```

and this is my client pc connection

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=192.168.1.101;Initial Catalog=Imatismos;user ID=admin;Password=1234");
```

Comment: What exactly do you want to archive?

Answer (score 1):

Well unless you specify the server name (if you are using `linked server`) the `Tamio.dbo.memberform` database is a local database getting used to my knowledge. In case, you want to use some other server DB and you have already defined `Linked Server` (using `sp_addlinkedserver`) for that then you can use saying

```
[server_name].Tamio.dbo.memberform
```

This is your local connection string and you are using a `local DB`

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(local);Initial Catalog=Tamio;Integrated Security=True");
```

Whereas, the other one is different server and don't have `Tamio` DB.

Comment: No i dont want to use linked server. In pc A i have database called Tamio, In  pc B i have a database called Imatismos.  Also i get this error Could not find server 'USER-PC\SQLEXPRESS.    My code : [USER-PC\\SQLEXPRESS].Tamio.dbo.memberform

Comment: @user6453809, You don't need to access it that way, since it's a local DB just use it like `Tamio.dbo.memberform`. no need of including server name. It's get inferred implicitly.

Comment: When i use it like this Tamio.dbo.memberform it searchs my database  to second pc B . My code is above

Comment: Lets say that i want to send from one pc-A to another pc-B through network. How will i do this. I will use something like this? SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into Tamio.memberform.name select Imatismos.customermaster.name ", conn); OR w ecan go in chat if you want

Comment: @user6453809, can't go in chat, it's my sleep time (it's highly late night @ my end). per your comment, make sure that the table/DB do exist i other server and yes you can form that query except that you can't directly access it since it's in a different server. That's why in answer I said use *linked server*. That's the only way to go. once you have created linked server then you can directly say `insert into Tamio.memberform.name select * from otherserver.Imatismos.customermaster.name`

Comment: And where should i write my other pc IP. Ex. 192.168.1.101? Or it doesnt need?

Comment: @user6453809, you are not reading my answer/comment properly. I said, you need to create a linked server for that. Please read here in MSDN https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/ff772782.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Four-part syntax `server.db.schema.object` to access different server is only applicable if you configured linked server in the server you are connected to. To use ad-hoc connection use OPENDATASOURCE https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179856.aspx